# If penis reconstruction from a clitoris is possible why isn't penis enlargement possible?

Tags: human-anatomy

I don't understand why, if a penis can be reconstructed from a clitoris for sex change, surgical penis enlargement is not possible.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your assertion that surgical penis enlargement is not possible?

Comment: @MattDMo there are options for surgical penis enlargement but they give maybe half an inch where as well I mean it's just no comparison to what they enlarge in a sex change

Comment: www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/sexual-health/in-depth/penis/art-20045363?pg=2

Comment: That's an interesting article. I though I had heard of implants to increase girth and help maintain erections for those with micropenis and injuries/other medical issues, respectively, that were similar in character to breast implants (i.e., they aren't resorbed by the body like a fat transplant).

Comment: @MattDMo silicon in such regions spells disaster it's painful it is eaten by the body and may cause other ailments

Comment: Micro penis is a disorder that is correctable with testostone otherwise nope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at urological sites for female-to-male reconstructive surgery the procedures often involve significant skin/tissue grafts and/or prostheses. See, e.g. [this interesting and somewhat graphic site.](http://www.savaperovic.com/ftm-srs-metoidioplasty-total-phalloplasty.htm)

Penis enlargement (see [this site](http://www.marksolomonmd.com/cosmetic-surgery/penis-enlargement.cfm)) for cosmetic purposes often entails less drastic measures, such as detaching the ligaments that keep part of the shaft inside the body or grafting (relatively small areas of) tissues to widen the penis. Weights are used to keep scar tissue from drawing the penis back into the body after surgery.

The seriousness of sex re-assignment surgery would seem to make it inappropriate
for a patient who wants a cosmetic versus a morphological change.

There is a huge urological literature on these topics but I think the above give an indication of why the two situations might call for different sorts of surgery.